# to begin with vs in the first place

Tags: phrases

I was wondering if it would be grammatically and idiomatically correct to use **to begin with** in the sense of

> used at the end of a sentence to talk about why something was done or
>   whether it should have been done or not

For example :

> If you don’t like her, why invite her in the first place?
>
> I should never have taken that job in the first place.

Is it possible to say :

If you don’t like her, why invite her to begin with?

I should never have taken that job to begin with.

Comment: Interesting. I'd always choose the 'in the first place' option, but the fourth sentence sounds not unacceptable.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - Sentence #3 doesn't quite get one slain by the fords of Jordan either. It does ring a trifle oddly for reasons I can't quie articulate.

Comment: Why add either? Don't the original sentences convey the same meaning in the form 'If you don't like her, why invite her?' and 'I should never have taken that job.'

Comment: @Icy The terminal 'in the first place' is idiomatic if redundant, and has a pragmatic role (emphasis) and a prosodic role.

Comment: @Rob “quie” should be quite?

Comment: I agree with Icy, though for emphasis I might add "at all".  For example:  If you don’t like her, why invite her at all."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it. You can google it and check for references; here's one that you can bear out, from
 [Invincible
By Dustin Humphreys](https://books.google.com/books?id=0siJDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT33&lpg=PT33&dq=I+should+never+have+taken+that+job+to+begin+with&source=bl&ots=Knmq5Nep7p&sig=9yhTFc-qY0-a_cP2WQAe9Tofr30&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1nPK0g5fZAhUS2GMKHTHZBMUQ6AEIJzAA0).

> "Listen, we should never have taken that job to begin with," he said.

Comment: Hello, Danelly. A single or a few Google hits don't license a usage as standard.

Comment: They mean the same thing, but if you say "first", you are implicitly promising at least one labelled "second", to follow, if not more. This is not true of _to begin with_.

Comment: @JohnLawler, that's part of what makes a term/phrase idiomatic, that is to say, it may not make a great deal of sense except as it's contextually understood via a priori usages. As to 'standard' idioms.. once an idiomatic expression is standard it can hardly be considered idiomatic any longer.

Answer (score 1):

"In the first place" and "To begin with" are both ok to be used at the end of a sentence (in the examples you provided). However, I hear "to begin with" used more in the beginning of a statement, rather than the end. For example:

> I should never have taken that job in the first place. To begin with,  it didn't even meet the minimum wage requirement.

or whatever reason. Basically:

> I should not have __________  in the first place. To begin with,  **** reason for previous sentence *****  .

Answer (score 0):

Both are used, "in the first place" more than "to begin with".
I've done three [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) queries but take them with a grain of salt.
[The first one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+begin+with%2Cin+the+first+place&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20begin%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20first%20place%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20begin%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20first%20place%3B%2Cc0) is a general search of the phrases not considering their position in the sentence.
[The second one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=first+place+_END_%2Cbegin+with+_END_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfirst%20place%20_END_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbegin%20with%20_END_%3B%2Cc0) does take the position at the end of the sentence into account but since Ngram can't do *START* or *END* operations with longer phrases the results are only for "first place" and "begin with".
So they're also not as accurate as I'd like them to be.
[The third one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+first+place+.%2Cto+begin+with+.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20first%20place%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20begin%20with%20.%3B%2Cc0) is done with a "." at the end of the phrase but that excludes sentences that end with "!" or "?" or any thing else.
In the end both are valid I think.

Answer (score -1):

"Never end a sentence in a preposition" is what they always told me in school. Therefore, I usually say "in the first place".

Comment: That is a myth or "zombie rule" https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/28/grammar-myths-prepositions/

Comment: You mean like "... up with which I will not put."? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I can't compete with these other answers! I will still express my opinion though. I think that all of the examples you asked about are grammatically correct, although I do feel that "in the first place" is more commonly used and sounds better. Still, they are interchangeable. I have also looked at some other sites, as this question seems to be one that is frequently asked, although do take each response in these sites with a grain of salt; they are written by people who may not be entirely correct.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-begin-with-vs-in-the-first-place.3594621/
https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/132798-in-the-first-place-or-To-begin-with-correct

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  This reads more like a comment than an answer, but stick around and you'll be able to leave comments soon.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site.  When you include links, it helps to quote the relevant material in the answer.

Answer (score -2):

In both cases, these “add-ons” at the end of the sentences are slang expressions.  “In the first place” implies there is a second place, a third place, etc.  “To begin with” implies there is a “to continue with” and a “to end with.”  Although both of these expressions are expectable as slang expressions go (I use them myself), they are both grammatically incorrect, with no correct alternatives.

Comment: Have you references supporting your views? Many idioms are extra-grammatical but totally acceptable, many even in formal registers.